# Updateprogress panel, CSS and removal of inline stlyes

Tags: css, ajax, updateprogress

This is driving me mental!!!

Ok, I have the following scenario - ModalPopupExtender used to display an UpdateProgress panel when AJAX is running. So I have the following:

```
<asp:Panel ID="panelUpdateProgress" runat="server" CssClass="updateProgress" >
            <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProg1" DisplayAfter="2" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static">
                <ProgressTemplate>
                    <div style="position: relative; top: 40%; text-align: center;">
                        <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Style="border: 0px; vertical-align: middle;
                            padding-bottom: 4px;" ImageUrl="~/Images/Refresh.gif" />
                        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Style="border: 0px; vertical-align: middle;
                            margin-left: 7px" Text="Refreshing data, please wait..."></asp:Label>
                 </div>
                </ProgressTemplate>
            </asp:UpdateProgress>
        </asp:Panel>
    <ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalProgress" runat="server"  TargetControlID="panelUpdateProgress"
        BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" PopupControlID="panelUpdateProgress">
    </ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>
```

Javascript to fire the thing when AJAX kicks ins:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    var ModalProgress = '<%= ModalProgress.ClientID %>';
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_beginRequest(beginReq);
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(endReq);
    function beginReq(sender, args) {
        // shows the Popup 
        $find(ModalProgress).show();
    }

    function endReq(sender, args) {
        //  Hides the Popup
        $find(ModalProgress).hide();
    } 
</script>
```

With the styling of :

```
<style type="text/css">
    .modalBackground
    {
        background-color: Gray;
        filter: alpha(opacity=50);
        opacity: 0.50;
    }

    .updateProgress
    {
        float: right;
        border-width: 1px;
        border-style: solid;
        background-color: #FAFAD2;
        width: 250px;
        height: 100px;
    }
</style>
```

However, I cannot for the life of me get the updateProgress to float right or adjust position (just as an example).

Using the developer tools, I can see that some sort of inline style overides the CSS style.

How on earth can I get, for example, my updateprogress to float right?

Answer (score 0):

If you're fighting against inline styles that you have no control over, this is one of those rare cases where the use of [`!important`](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/importantdeclarations) is actually justified:

Give this a try:

```
.updateProgress
{
    float: right !important;
    /* etc. */
}
```

If this doesn't work, try adding a `clear:right`, or using a more [specific](http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/) selector like:

```
#someElement .updateProgress {}
```

**EDIT**: Specificity in CSS selectors won't help against inline styles, so ignore that as a possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

well I've ditch the style sheet and run with this:

```
  <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProg1" DisplayAfter="2" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static">
            <ProgressTemplate>
                <div style="float: right; border-width: 1px; border-style: solid; background-color: #FAFAD2;
                    width: 250px; height: 100px;">
                    <div style="position: relative; top: 40%; text-align: center;">
                        <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Style="border: 0px; vertical-align: middle;
                            padding-bottom: 4px;" ImageUrl="~/Images/Refresh.gif" />
                        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Style="border: 0px; vertical-align: middle;
                            margin-left: 7px" Text="Refreshing data, please wait..."></asp:Label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </ProgressTemplate>
        </asp:UpdateProgress>
```

It does the business so I'm happy for now :D